# Cast string to date in pyarrow form a JSON string

Tags: python, json, date, database-schema, pyarrow

I have a JSON string:

```html
{
    "C_0_0":"2022-1-1"
}
```

I want to impose a schema .

```html
raw_schema = pa.schema([
                    pa.field("C_0_0", pa.string()), 
    
])

new_schema = pa.schema([
                    pa.field("C_0_0", pa.date32()), 
    
])
```

I am reading the schema in this way :

```html
file_path = '/home/i574375/views/links/gitenv/gitsrc/sqla/src/db/engine/datalake_shared_resources/tests/pyunit/testscripts/datalake/abc.json'
table = pajson.read_json(file_path, parse_options = pajson.ParseOptions(explicit_schema = raw_schema))
table = table.cast(new_schema)
```

But I face this error:

```
pyarrow.lib.ArrowNotImplementedError: Unsupported cast from string to date32 using function cast_date32
```

How to fix the issue?

Comment: not sure if this is related https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/28303

Comment: But it does not provide a solution for string to date right?

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: Would casting to `pa.timestamp` be an option?

Answer (score 0):

Casting from string to date is an opinionated process that requires you to provide the format for you date.

If you have `foo.json`:

```json
{"C_0_0":"2022-01-01"}
```

Then you can use pyarrow compute to convert from string to timestamp and then date:

```py
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.json as pajson
import pyarrow.compute as pc

raw_schema = pa.schema([
                    pa.field("C_0_0", pa.string()), 
    
])

file_path = 'foo.json'
table = pajson.read_json(file_path, parse_options = pajson.ParseOptions(explicit_schema = raw_schema))


table.set_column(
    table.schema.get_field_index("C_0_0"),
    "C_0_0",
    pc.strptime(table['C_0_0'], format="%Y-%m-%d", unit='s').cast(pa.date32())
)
```

The problem is that your date format is `"%Y-%-m-%-d"` (`2022-1-1` vs `2022-01-01`) which is not supported by arrow at the moment.

You can try to play around the [string functions](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/api/compute.html#string-splitting) in arrow compute to either put back the leading zeros in, or split the string in 3 integers to build a date.